# JDialog stays in Swings Component-Tree after it's closed

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, window, lifecycle

I have a Dialog-View that uses a PropertyListener to propagate events to the caller.
We use the swing components built-in PropertyListeners. Now, we open one of these dialogs and then the user closes it via the "X" button in the system. Later on we call the following snippet:

```java
  for ( final Window frame : Frame.getFrames() )
  {
    updateAllUIs( frame );
  }

  private static void updateAllUIs( final Window frame )
  {
    for ( final Window childWindow : frame.getOwnedWindows() )
    {
      updateAllUIs( childWindow );
    }
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( frame );
  }
```

Apparently this even reaches dialogs that have long been closed. Whether `dispose` has been called or not doesn't make a difference either. Is there a sure-fire way to make sure that Swing doesn't hold any more internal references to dialogs that aren't in use anymore? While we should've cleared our listeners, this still shouldn't happen. Or do I missunderstand something here?

Minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```java
package dialogleak;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DialogLeak
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

    JButton dialogButton = new JButton( "Dialog" );
    dialogButton.addActionListener( __ ->
    {
      JDialog dialog = new JDialog( mainFrame );
      dialog.setModal( true );
      dialog.add( new JTextField( "Hello world" ) );
      dialog.getRootPane().addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt )
        {
          //Shouldn't be visible when dialog is invisible.
          System.out.println( "Fired: " + evt.getPropertyName() + "; Dialog visible: " + dialog.isVisible() );
        }
      } );
      dialog.setSize( 200, 100 );
      dialog.setLocationRelativeTo( mainFrame );
      //Doesn't make a difference, feel free to try.
      //dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation( JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
      dialog.setVisible( true );
    } );

    JButton updateUIButton = new JButton( "Update UI" );
    updateUIButton.addActionListener( __ ->
    {
      for ( Frame frame : Frame.getFrames() )
      {
        updateUIRecursively( frame );
      }
    } );

    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    mainFrame.add( panel );
    panel.add( dialogButton, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    panel.add( updateUIButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    mainFrame.setSize( 400, 300 );
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
  }

  private static void updateUIRecursively( Window window )
  {
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( window );
    for ( final Window childWindow : window.getOwnedWindows() )
    {
      updateUIRecursively( childWindow );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the value for setDefaultCloseOperation? I think it is HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default, you may need DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Comment: I have manually called "dispose()" in a WindowListener that listens to close events. Shouldn't that have been enough?

Comment: I didn't have time to try it I'm afraid as I'm at work. But if my hazy memory works properly dispose only get's rid of native screen resources so maybe the components themselves still exist and are not GC'd. You may have to manually remove the JDialog from the Swing tree's children. Sorry, not very helpful.

Comment: How would I even do that? It appears the the dialogs are returned in the "getOwnedWindows" call of a frame. So, the frame thinks it still holds children dialogs.

Comment: You could try calling remove(dialog) on the parent of the dialog,

Comment: That sounds like it may work, but I am still asking myself whether this is normal. I've never ever seen anyone doing something like this.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [mcve]?

Comment: Done, I've added an example

Comment: MAYBE this is a XY problem. The goal there was to refresh all active components after changing UIManager-Values. E.g. "Reapplying" the look and feel you might say. Is there a more correct way to do this instead?